# Los parámetros son visibles con https?

Tags: https

Estoy utilizando una rest API la cual sigue este esquema:
https://myapi.com/userId/1?masterKey=123456

Mi preocupación es si dicha "master key" es visible a través de todo internet o la url va cifrada?

Comment: y es necesario sea visible? digo por que asumo que viaja por el métod GET no?

Comment: efectivamente hablamos de un GET y no, simplemente quiero entender si es seguro mandar una clave como parámetro con https

Comment: pues claramente no, lo mejor es que si vas a enviar datos sensibles sea por el método POST para que esos datos viajen protegidos

Answer (score 1):

Si, de hecho si lo quieres ver puedes usar una extension en chrome llamada Request Maker, te deja ver toda la información que pasa como parámetro a través de  http

Answer (score 1):

La teoría dice que no, pues la negociación entre cliente y servidor para montar el túnel encriptado ocurre antes de la petición http.

Esto significa que el proveedor de internet del cliente (o el administrador del router/gateway en un caso de free wifi) verá el dominio y no el resto de la URL.

Dependiendo del tipo de negociación y/o si el cliente tiene la ip cacheada o usa otro dns, solo vera la IP (pero es fácil hacer un reverse).

El resto de la internet sólo verá el tráfico del tunel.

En la práctica internet no ve la petición en si misma, pero si es llamada desde javascript y la página es pública pues si.

refs:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/8858102/1423096

https://superuser.com/q/231991/814139

https://stackoverflow.com/q/499591/1423096

https://media.ccc.de/v/27c3-4301-en-flow_analysis_of_internet_activities